showing NP completeness for XS
the XS problem:
Input: n final sets and a number k (final sets - finite set of numbers, and k's value can be at most n).
Question: Are there k sets in the n final ones that are not pairwise disjoint?
I need to show that XS is np-complete. the first part of proving that it's in NP was fine, and I got a hint to reduce from CLIQUE, but I can't think of a move with this one.

Hint: the problem relates to the Clique problem just as the Set Packing problem relates to the Independent Set problem.
To keep the post self-contained, I will quote the reduction from the Independent Set problem:

 Given an independent vertex set problem on a graph $G(V,E)$, build a collection of sets where for each vertex $v$ there is a set $S_{v}$ containing all edges adjacent to $v$. Every set packing in the generated collection corresponds to an independent vertex set in $G(V,E)$.


Ok so I thought of something, I wonder if it's any good. Each group will be represented by each node, and its elements will be the edges that go through this node. Then, because we are looking at an undirected graph, the edge (Vi, Vj)=(Vj, Vi), so the group Vi with the edge (Vi, Vj) will intersect with the group Vj. Thus, the K that represents the clique will also represent the wanted groups. How does this sound to you?

Yes, that's correct. If a set of vertices $U$ forms a clique, then the associated sets formed by a reduction will also be pairwise not disjoint.
